# Cannot start Android Emulator on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

I'm trying to use Android Emulator on my Dell laptop with OS Ubuntu 20.04.3 but when i try to start it stuck on loading screen. Running it with ./emulator @AVD_NAME -verbose it print out:

```
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196608'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'front'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '440'
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=/home/*****/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img,read-only: Could not open '/home/*****/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img': Operation not permitted
emulator: Done with QEMU main loop
```

Actually directory, and it's parent, had 777 permission. What it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I was helping to analyze the same problem for my coworker. What turned out was that it was network issue and also (probably) Antivirus issue. Smaller files like ramdisk.img were just fine but bigger files like system.img were corrupted. There was no error message when those files were downloaded through Android Studio or browser. They looked fine and even had proper size on disc, however when we've executed **md5sum** on those files the smaller ones just printed checksum while bigger ones were printing "**Operation not permitted**". The same as in your logs. When we've bypassed those problems (by dividing image files into chunks and encrypting them) then everything was fine till the point when files were decrypted on my coworker PC. After decryption issue ("Operation not permitted") hit again, so that's why we think it's Antivirus thing.